# ipywidgets: identify which widget is being observed

Tags: python, widget, ipywidgets

I need to create a variable number of widgets and then identify which widget is being observed when the user interacts with one of them. In the following example, *n* `IntSliders` are being created:

```
import ipywidgets as wg
def obs(change):
    print(change)
def fun(n):
    l  = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(wg.IntSlider())
        l[i].observe(obs, names='value')
    display(wg.VBox(l))
fun(4)
```

When interacting with one of the sliders, the `change` variable only gives the values for *owner*, *old*, *new*, *type* and *name*.

```
{'owner': IntSlider(value=1), 'new': 1, 'old': 0, 'type': 'change', 'name': 'value'}
```

I would like to "tweak" the content of `change` to include its position in the list *l*.

**Note:** I cannot use existing `IntSlider` attributes like *description* because then it will be reflected in the widget appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is given in [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2118).